# sybase check if a datetime is within time

Tags: sybase

I have a column with datetime as the data type

I need to check if that datetime column is between 2:30pm to 3pm, "ignoring" the date

I saw an example in sql server that cast the datetime to float but that did not work in sybase...

does anyone have any idea

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Floor your datetime to midnight of that date, Then use datediff() to get the elapsed time between the two.

```
DECLARE @dt DATETIME

SET @dt='10/06/2011 2:37:17.390PM'

SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN DATEDIFF(ms,CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(DATE,@dt)),@dt) BETWEEN 52200000 AND 54000000
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END
```